MKLocalSearchCompleter empty queryFragment error
Question is basically the title.
When passing in to queryFragment, i get a call to
func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error)
with the following error: Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={MKErrorGEOError=-7}
I do not full get how to check these errors? Are they MKError? what is a MKErrorGEOError? I cannot find documentation for that.
I want to be able to explicitly detect that the user searched an empty queryFragment in this error handle and handle it differently than other errors.
